# Average cross entropy for 3D tensors

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch, loss-function, cross-entropy

I have an output tensor (both target and predicted) of dimension (32 x 8 x 5000). Here, the batch size is 32, the number of classes is 5000 and the number of points per batch is 8. I want to calculate CELoss on this in such a way that, the loss is computed for every point (across 5000 classes) and then averaged across the 8 points. How can I do this?

For clarity, there are 32 *batch points* in a batch (for bs=32). Each batch point has 8 *vector points*, and each vector point has 5000 classes. For a given batch, I wish to compute CELoss across all (8) *vector points*, compute their average and do so for all the *batch points* (32).

Let me know if my question isn’t clear or ambiguous.

For example:

```
op = torch.rand((4,3,5))

gt = torch.tensor([
    [[0,1,1,0,0],[0,0,1,0,0],[1,1,0,0,1]],
    [[1,1,0,0,1],[0,0,0,1,0],[0,0,1,0,0]],
    [[0,0,1,0,0],[1,1,1,1,0],[1,1,0,0,1]],
    [[1,1,0,0,1],[1,1,0,0,1],[1,0,0,0,0]]
])
```

Comment: can you provide a reproducible example with a reduced-size batch?

Comment: [Salvatore](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11728488/salvatore-daniele-bianco) I've updated the question. Let me know if something else would be needed

Comment: sorry, but I expect to have a single true class in `gt` for each point of each element instead of multiple class in the vectors. Am I wrong? I mean that `gt.sum(dim=-1)` has to return a tensor of ones with shape `batch_size x points`

Comment: In this case, I'm expecting multiple true values for every point

Comment: ok. In this case your problem is not to classify the points in 5000 classes. Your problem is to perform 5000 binary classifications. So you have to use binary cross entropy rather than multi-class cross entropy. Am I right?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. In my case, i don't want to predict multiple classes at the same time. Rather, I'm looking for the model to predict any one/many of the ground truths

Comment: Conceptually, a given sample in exactly one class (say, class 3), but for training purposes, predicting class 2 or 5 is still okay so the model isn't penalized too heavily. This explains the multiple 1s for a given example's ground truth.

Comment: OK, but in this case simply you can't apply the cross-entropy loss. you should define a  custom loss function based on this specific task.

Comment: Yeah. I'm stuck designing this custom loss in itself. There aren't a lot of resources for tasks similar to this

Comment: I think the binary cross-entropy approach might work.

Comment: Won't BCE force the model to predict all classes?

Comment: of course not. Conceptually it is like training 5000 separate binary classifiers optimized to predict the probability of each class independently from other classes. Try to train and over-fit a model in this way to see how it works.

Answer (score 0):

DATA

```
op = torch.rand((4,3,5))
gt = torch.tensor([
    [[0,1,1,0,0],[0,0,1,0,0],[1,1,0,0,1]],
    [[1,1,0,0,1],[0,0,0,1,0],[0,0,1,0,0]],
    [[0,0,1,0,0],[1,1,1,1,0],[1,1,0,0,1]],
    [[1,1,0,0,1],[1,1,0,0,1],[1,0,0,0,0]]
], dtype=torch.float)
```

Now, if your output is in `[0,1]` (if it is not please provide a Sigmoid activation at the end of your model) you can compute the binary cross-entropy losses (`N_class` values for each point of each element) in this way:

```
torch.nn.BCELoss(reduction="none")(op, gt)
```

You can finally compute the average loss for each element of batch as:

```
torch.nn.BCELoss(reduction="none")(op, gt).mean(dim=[-1,-2])
```

If it is not the solution you are looking for or it is not clear let me know.